# How the attributes of god 'Rehman' and 'Raheem' different

Tags: allah, asma-ul-husna

Except surah 'tauba' all surah of Qur'an starts with "bismillah ar rehman ir Raheem".
How being rehmaan and being Raheem different?

An aalim explained that Allah is rehmaan for all the creatures. It does not matter if they believe in god or not, it does not matter they are good or bad.

And Allah is Raheem for some selected people.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Rahman" means merciful for all (believer or non-believer). Like sending rain, food,...

"Rahim" means merciful for believers only.

Allah has two kind of mercy. One is for all. And one type is extra only for believers (Mumenin).

[Source](http://www.shiasource.com/al-mizan/tafsir/1-1-5/)

Comment: i agree with your answer, lets wait for some other answers for 1 more day. then i will accept it

Answer (score 3):

Some aalims (scholars) say: "Rahman" is a name ("Esm") not attribute, just for god. But "Rahim" is an attribute which used for passenger "Mohammad (ص)" in surah "tauba".
Two reasons are explained:

1. We can replace "Allah" instead of "Rahman" everywhere in the Quran.
2. "Rahim" used just in kindness of him, but "Rahman" used everywhere.

From [here](http://quran.al-shia.org/).

Answer (score 1):

Both words are primarily adjectives. Rahman is used both as a proper noun for God (e.g. [17:110](http://tanzil.net/#17:110)) as well as an adjective (e.g. [59:22](http://tanzil.net/#59:22)):

Since you asked this question in reference to *Bismillah*, it should be noted that both are used as attributes here. Both words allude to different shades of meaning of `رحمة` (kindness):

1. Rahman indicates the high intensity of `رحمة` and
2. Rahim refers to its perpetuity.

Let me quote [Islahi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amin_Ahsan_Islahi). He [writes](http://www.renaissance.com.pk/janqur2y1.htm):

> The noun **Rahman** is the intensive form of Fa‘lan (eg: Sakran and
>   Gadban), while the noun ***Rahim*** is an adjective of the form Fa‘il (eg:
>   ‘Alim and Karim). A look at the usage of the Arabic language shows
>   that the form Fa‘lan expresses **great fervency and enthusiasm**, while
>   the form Fa‘il expresses ***steadiness and perpetuity***. In other words,
>   the first depicts **vigour** and the second ***constancy*** in God’s mercy. A
>   little deliberation shows that the Almighty’s mercy on His creation
>   possesses both these characteristics. The **enthusiasm and warmth** is
>   complemented by ***permanence***. It is not that His attribute of **Rahman**
>   induced Him to create, and He later forgot to foster and sustain His
>   creation. Indeed, He is nourishing and taking proper care of them
>   because He is ***Rahim*** as well. Whenever a person invokes His help, He
>   hears his calls and accepts his prayers. Also, His blessings are not
>   confined to this world only. Those who lead their lives according to
>   the path prescribed by Him, shall be blessed with eternal life and
>   joy. It must be conceded that all these aspects cannot be comprehended
>   without an integrated understanding of these attributes.